# Search selected text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, browser-addons, selection

What are the different Firefox extensions that can start a search with the selected text?

Firefox has an inbuilt feature to search using the **currently** selected engine.

- Select any text
- Right click the selection
- Search Google for ...

I'm looking for something that will let me **choose** which search engine I want to search with, from my current list of installed search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Context Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/240) is another option, works great.

Comment: +1 - Amazing addon since it uses my existing list of search engines, exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox addon [Smart Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartsearch/) appears to do what you are looking for.

[image: Smart Search]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the add-on [SearchWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchwith/).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this addon [basic shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/basic-shortcuts/).

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>: Search google for selected text
- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>: mail current url